# Navigate to previous screen with updated data from api using GetX state management flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

When I navigate back from update screen after updating I am uable to fetch updated data.

Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [
Text("General Detail",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Roboto',fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
IconButton(onPressed: (){
Get.to(()=>UpdateDetailView())!.whenComplete(()=>profileController.fetchProfileDataDetails());
}, icon: Icon(Icons.edit))
],
),

Comment: share your code

Comment: i think you need to await for that page.please share more code so others can understand